# Reading /dev/usb/hiddev0 file generated by thermocouple board

Tags: raspbian, usb, input-device

I recently purchased a TMPSNSRD-TCPL1 thermocouple reference design from Microchip.  When I plug it into the RPI with the USB cable, it generates a character device file /dev/usb/biddev0.  I have been trying to interrogate this file using cat and open commands but with no success. 
Please help!!

Comment: What are the results of your attempts?  Was there an error or just no data?

Answer (score 2):

to be able to access your plugged in device, you should use `lsusb` command to find the device manufacturer and product code like this:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 045e:0047 Microsoft Corp. IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
$
```

For example, I can see my mouse has ID 045e:0047, then add the line to the `/etc/udev/rules.d/69-thermo.rules`:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0047", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

replacing the `Vendor` and `Product` numbers with the ones you've found with `lsusb` command.

Finally, you have to add yourself to the group 'plugdev':

```
sudo adduser user plugdev
```

where `user` is your user name (use `who` to find out if unsure).

After that you might need reboot, relogon or just reinsert your device depending on the settings you've changed.